# using an enum when a class already exists for it?

Tags: c#, enums, constants

I have a class defined as below:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    //... additional properties ...
}
```

My database has approximately 10 categories in it, and the set is unlikely to change in the future (though it is possible new categories will be added sporadically). Each category has a number of fields associated with it.

For the most part, other classes are populated with only the category's `Id`. I need to perform different actions based on the specific category.

For example:

```
if (categoryId == 1)
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    //do something else
}
```

**I'm looking to avoid hardcoded values when doing this.**

I would typically use an enum for this purpose, but I'm not sure how to structure it in this case, since I already have a class for it. One idea is to create a separate enum called `CategoryEnum`, but this seems smelly. Another option is to use class constants.

What is the clearest way to compare the category `Id` against a specific constant value?

Comment: What is category? What does the categoryID 1 represents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Antarr Byrd's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13181259/370671), it seemed that using class constants made for the clearest code.

```
public class Category
{
    public const int CATEGORY_ONE = 1;
    public const int CATEGORY_TWO = 2;
    //etc.

    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    //... additional properties ...
}
```

And for comparing:

```
if (categoryId == Category.CATEGORY_ONE)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
public enum CategoryId { ... }

public class Category
{
    public CategoryId Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    //... additional properties ...
}
```

The enum describes the ID, while the rest of your class adds other useful information.

---

If you want to leave this as an `int` property, you can still use the enum:

```
public enum CategoryId { ... }

public class Category
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    //... additional properties ...
}
```

Then when you need to test the value:

```
switch ((CategoryId)myCategory.Id)
{ ... }
```

Comment: I would prefer not to change the existing implementation of the Id field, since it's tied to the PK of the database and is used in many other places.

Comment: @RyanKohn by default, and `enum` is really an `int`, so it's fundamentally not different. Note that you can leave it as is and still use the enum. I'll edit...

Answer (score 1):

If i understand quetion correctly this should be a valid implementation.

```
if(categoryId == (int)Category.CategoryOne)
{
 ...
}
else 
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: To clarify: you're suggesting using class constants?

Comment: Yes this is almost how we do it every time